# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

Tags: elasticsearch, gradle, grails

It is the first time ever that I am using ES Java API Client in grails app. I am following the instructions here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/installation.html

Everything was installed properly, the packages were identified.

As part of my `Bootstrap.groovy` I am trying to make sure that an index exists.

**Bootstrap.groovy**

```
class BootStrap {

    JobSchedulerService jobSchedulerService
    ProjectSearchService projectSearchService

    def init = { servletContext ->
        jobSchedulerService.startup()
        projectSearchService.createIndex()
    }

    def destroy = {
        jobSchedulerService.shutdown()
    }
}
```

Where `createIndex` inside `ProjectSearchService` is as follows:

```
class ProjectSearchService {

    ElasticSearchClientProviderService elasticSearchClientProviderService

    void createIndex() {
        ElasticsearchIndicesClient elasticsearchIndicesClient =
            elasticSearchClientProviderService.getClient().indices()

        boolean exists = elasticsearchIndicesClient.exists({ c ->
            c.index("projects")
        }).value()

        if (!exists) {
            elasticsearchIndicesClient.create({ c ->
                c.index("projects")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Where `elasticSearchClientProviderService.getClient()` is:

```
class ElasticSearchClientProviderService {

    ElasticsearchClient client

    ElasticsearchClient getClient() {
        if (!client) {
            // Create the low-level client
            RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9200)).build();

            // Create the transport with a Jackson mapper
            ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(
                restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

            // And create the API client
            client = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);
        }

        client
    }
}
```

Everything is pretty straightforward, but when I am trying to run the app I am getting the following error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-12-20 02:49:21.237 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1181)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:84)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:393)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:380)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
        at priz.Application.main(Application.groovy:13)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:588)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:57)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:66)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.<init>(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:182)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.createRequestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:559)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:525)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c86fad3e.CGLIB$requestMappingHandlerAdapter$21(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c86fad3e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c6ce1302.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c86fad3e.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Following this cause:
`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`
The class is there (at least I can find it manually).

In my build.gradle I have these two related dependencies:

```
    compile 'co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:7.16.2'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.3'
```

Here is the output of `gradle dependencies`:

https://gist.github.com/ShurikAg/1c539096c9a16daaac0173cd4c672738

Seems like everything is in place.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was using a `pom.xml` file and was getting the same error.

[THIS](https://springframework.guru/jackson-dependency-issue-spring-boot-maven/) worked for me

**TLTR**: Use `<exclusion>`

```
. . .
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
</dependency>
. . .
```